# Reopening spritekit scene

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, skscene

Scenario in my game:

main menu -> game setup menu -> core game scene -> game menu (load/save/quit) -> core game scene -> game menu (here stuff stops working).

Each segment is it's own SKScene and presented from one to other. Game data is stored in static class that can be accessed from all classes.
When I first time start game and come into core game scene, everything is ok. I can open game menu and close it again (returning to core game scene). But when I wish to open game menu scene again it does not fire didMoveToView function and nothing happens.
I have made all transitions between scenes  with the same principle and going from main menu scene to game setup and back works normaly, I can do it multiple times. Even tried without transition, but something isn't working well here... Seems I can't find solution here :(

AppDelegate is pretty straigt forward:

```
if let scene = MainMenu(fileNamed:"MainMenu")
{
    scene.size = CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
    scene.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.5)
    self.skView!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    self.skView!.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    self.skView!.showsFPS = true
    self.skView!.showsNodeCount = true

    window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
}
```

In MainMenu class instancing QuickGame class/scene where player setup game:

```
if let quickGameScene = QuickGame(fileNamed: "QuickGame")
{
    quickGameScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
    quickGameScene.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.5)
    view?.presentScene(quickGameScene, transition: transition)
}
```

And in QuickGame instancing CoreGame class where core game logic is "processed":

```
gameData = GameData()
player.race = selectedRace
GameData.player = player;
GameData.background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bground")
GameData.background.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
GameData.background.position = CGPoint.zero
GameData.background.zPosition = 0

if let coreGame = CoreGame(fileNamed: "QuickGame")
{
    coreGame.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
    coreGame.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.5)
    view?.presentScene(coreGame, transition: transition)
}
```

Here note GameData class, it is essentially class holding static properties that can be transferred from one scene to other. Idea here is, that when player goes into maingamemenu, core game scene is paused but not destroyed, until player starts new game or quits game. If main game menu is closed, core game should be resumed from prevoious state!

Here is GameData:

```
class GameData
{ 
static var player = Player() 
static var background = SKSpriteNode() 
static var alreadyInitialized = false
static var mainGameMenuCreated = false
}
```

And MainGameMenu instancing in CoreGame class:

And MainGameMenu instancing in CoreGame class:

```
if let mainGameMenu = MainGameMenu(fileNamed: "MainGameMenu")
{
    mainGameMenu.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
    mainGameMenu.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.5)
    view?.presentScene(mainGameMenu, transition: transition)
}
```

And instancing CoreGAme back inside MainGameMenu:

```
if let coreGame = CoreGame(fileNamed: "CoreGame") 
{ 
    coreGame.scaleMode = self.scaleMode 
    coreGame.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor() 
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.5)
    view?.presentScene(coreGame, transition: transition) 
}
```

Anything else needed? Sorry for code mess, but editing code here is nerve cracking...

Comment: Can you share some code that can replicate the issue?

Comment: Yikes,  are you sure that your old scenes are being removed? Also, it seems like view? is not the behavior you want,  when you are presenting your scene, you want to make sure view is not nil, so perhaps have an assert that fires off if your view is nil,  this may help you trace your problem

Comment: How do I check if old scene was removed and how can I keep a scene for future work if needed?

Comment: override deinit and print("Class deinit),  as for your second one, just have a variable retain it,  but I would not do this, you will run out of resources this way.

Comment: Ok we are something into here. I put in deinit sections in all scene classes and none is called except MainGameMenu is called everytime except first time I try to open it. So as it seems scenes are not deallocated, but question remains why I can for example go back and forth between MainMenu and QuickGame scene and not CoreGame and MainGameMenu. Only difference is that I have initialized GameData, but this class is containg static properties that can be accessible from anywhere... Is it possible to reuse old scene instead of always creating new one? Documentation is not really rich about this.